# Efficient way of implementing a Custom LinkedHashMap

Tags: java, performance, dictionary

I want to implement a custom `LinkedHashMap` that has a few more methods/some have different from the `LinkedHashMap`. I was thinking about making it over a `LinkedHashMap` and changin the implementations for whatever I want and for the rest, just call the methods from the LHM.

Is that efficient? Something like:

```
public class CustomLHM<K, V> implements Map<K, V>{

    private final HashMap<K, V> entries;

    public CustomLHM() {
        entries = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    }
```

SO for methods like `containsKey` , `containsValue`... I'd just do a return entries.containsKey(key) so basically just calling the method from the already java implemented `LinkedHashMap`. My question is... is there a better way to do this? A more efficient way to implement it?

Is it more efficient if I implement it myself with basic structures like the actual implementation of the LHM?

Comment: Why not _extend_ `LinkedHashMap<K,V>`?

Comment: @JimGarrison beat me to it :-)

Comment: I'm stuck on just implementing over the `Map` interface so I can't change the definition

Comment: Can't you do `public class CustomLHM<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> implements Map<K, V>`?

Comment: @NemanjaT surely `implements Map<K, V>` is implied by `extends LinkedHashMap<K, V>`?

Comment: @AndyTurner he says he needs to extend Map (probably polimor reasons), but he can also extend for other purposes. It's not really an unusual thing to do.

Comment: @NemanjaT it's simply redundant. `LinkedHashMap<K, V>` is a `Map<K, V>` already. It's like declaring `extends Object`.

Comment: If you want to make a `Map` method do something different, you should be aware of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).  Basically, it states that anything that is a `Map` should always do exactly what a `Map` is supposed to do.  If you don't want to do that, then your custom class could use a `Map` internally without actually being a `Map` itself.

Comment: @AndyTurner I agree, it is redundant and should be avoided, but simply sometimes is usable. Say A implements B and you're making a class C that implements A and extends B, now, due to polimor, you put B as argument in certain methods, but B, naturally, doesn't have all the methods A has. Removing implementation of B would require a lot of refactoring etc. Don't get me wrong, I agree that it's redundant and should be avoided as much as possible. Spring Boot has this issue with WebLogic BTW (as an example that it happens), you extend a class and implement an interface that are both related.

Comment: I using guava's tests to make sure that my implementation still respects what being a Map is though. I can't extend 'LinkedHashMap' because I'm supposed to just implement Map and that's all. I was just wondering if there's any reason for me to use the basic implementation with Entry<K,V>, efficiency wise, even a little or I can just as well go on and have composition

Comment: @Mocktheduck you keep on talking about "efficiency": what do you actually mean when you say that? Especially given the fact that you "can't extend 'LinkedHashMap'" implying that this is just a homework exercise, *correctness* should be your primary (if not only) concern.

Answer (score 0):

That is the **delegate** pattern, delegating all calls to one field.

Tip:

> If the IDE cannot do that for you, first override, then call the IDE's override all methods, replace "super." with "entries.".

Efficiency is not really a matter, especially with the JIT compiler.

As even in the latest java compiler HashMap was improved (buckets with tree sets I believe), I would refrain from an own implementation of something needing production quality solidity. Or better: not needing maintenance.